# Using IAM roles transitively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a question on using IAM roles with EC2 and EMR. Here's my current setup:

I have a EC2 machine launched with a particular IAM role (let's call this role 'admin'). My workflow is to upload a file to S3 from this machine and then create an EMR cluster with a particular IAM role (a 'runner' role). The EMR cluster works on the file uploaded to S3 from the admin machine.
Admin is a role with privileges to all APIs in all AWS services. Runner has access to all APIs in EMR, EC2 and S3.

For some reason, the EMR cluster is unable to access the input file loaded in S3. It keeps getting an 'access denied' exception from s3.

I guess writing to s3 from one IAM role and reading it from a different IAM role is what is causing the issue.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here or whether this is even a supported use-case is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc

S3 objects are protected in three ways as seen in the post I linked to.

1. Your IAM role will need the permission to read S3 objects.
2. The S3 bucket policy must allow your IAM role access to the object.
3. The S3 ACL for the specific object must also allow your IAM role access to the object.